# How to change background-color of webpage every 5 seconds using an array of colors?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the `bgcolor` of my webpage every 5 seconds and the `color` must come from an array. This is what I've done so far:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var c = ["blue", "black", "yellow", "red"];

  function changeColor() {
    setTimeout(function loop() {
      document.bgColor = c.shift();
      if (c.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 5000);
      }
    }, 5000);
  }

  function start() {
    setInterval(changeColor(), 20000);
  }
</script>

<body onload="start()">
</body>
```

Assumed that I have 4 colors, each color stays for 5 seconds, so 5*4 = 20 seconds and with `setInterval` every 20 seconds i recall the `changeColor()` function to make a sort of infinite loop on the array, but it does not work properly, as it looks like the start() function calls only one time changeColor(), but I wan it called every 20 seconds.
Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well for starters you are _not_ calling your function every 20 seconds - you called it *once*, because that is what `changeColor()` _does_. You need to pass the _reference_ to a function to setInterval, not the undefined return value of your function _call_.

Answer (score 2):

From here: [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element.

So, you are left with an empty array after 4 iterations. Just use the following code, which is much simpler and doesn't mutate your array.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var c = ["blue", "black", "yellow", "red"];
  var currentColorIndex = 0;

  function changeColor() {
    document.bgColor = c[currentColorIndex];
    currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % c.length;
    setTimeout(changeColor, 5000);
  }

</script>

<body onload="changeColor()">
</body>
```

Comment: `each color stays for 5 seconds` !

Comment: Fixed it, but I think that topic answer intelligent enough to understand which value responsible for this.

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't encourage the hard coding of the length of the array, the better alternative is to use `c.length - 1`. Also, in the case of your code it should be `3` rather than `4`.  An alternative way of doing this is also `currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % c.length`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

just use `setInterval` to run the function every 5sec

```js
var c=["blue","green","yellow","red"];
  function changeColor(){
        var randomcolor = c[Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length)];
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomcolor;
            
        }
function start(){
             setInterval(changeColor, 5000);
  }
  
  start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var c = ["blue", "black", "yellow", "red"];
  function changeColor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
     (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.bgColor = c[i];
        }, 5000 * i);
    })(i);
  }
}
</script>

<body onload="changeColor()">
</body>
```